# How to change filenames of files with no type in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to rename a bunch of files, replacing a particular string using a bash script with `find` and `rename`. This is working for files when I specify a filetype, but I have a number of files I need to change that have no file type and I can't figure out how to rename them.

For files with a filetype, I'm using this successfully to replace $old_session with $new_session, for example in each .jpg file:

```
old_session='123'
new_session='456'
find my_folder -name '*.jpg' -type f -exec rename $old_session $new_session *.jpg {} \;
```

But when I try to do the same thing for files that don't have a filetype, nothing happens:

```
find my_folder -name '*' -type f -exec rename $old_session $new_session * {} \;
```

or

```
find my_folder -name '*${old_session}*' -type f -exec rename $old_session $new_session *${old_session}* {} \;
```

How can I change the filename of files with no type specified?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for pattern `*.jpg` because there are no `jpg` files in the folder you're running `find` on and the shell passes `*.jpg` unexpanded to the `find` command which passes it unexpanded to `rename` and it works.

But when you do:

```
find my_folder -name '*' -type f -exec rename $old_session $new_session * {} \;
```

the `*` is expanded with *all files from current dir* and passed to `rename` as-is, and that's not what you want.

Do that instead:

```
find my_folder -name '*' -type f -exec rename $old_session $new_session "*" {} \;
```

(that's also better for `.jpg` files BTW :))

Comment: This works, but it doesn't change files where the $old_session is in the filename twice. Is there a way to do that in the same line, or do I need to run it a second time?

Comment: rename man says: "rename will rename the specified files by replacing the first
       occurrence of expression in their name by replacement.". So it's a no-go. But you could create a `multirename` script which would take the same arguments and would do what you want.

Comment: I'm warning you that creating a `multirename` script isn't trivial, with filenames with spaces, etc... so if you want to go that way prepare for another question on stackoverflow :) running it twice would be simpler for the rare cases you'll encounter.

Comment: If trying to showcase good practices here, some additional quoting is called for. `$old_session` isn't guaranteed to be identical to `"$old_session"`.

Answer (score 0):

I would  do it like this:

Lets say our "old_session" is kkk and our "new_session" is "noname"

Consider the following files in the directory. A couple of kkk and .sh files.

```
bash$> ls -lrt
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  7 03:03 3432kkk
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  7 03:03 334kkk
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  7 03:03 222kkk
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  7 03:03 190kkk
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  7 03:03 123kkk
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  7 03:03 c.sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  7 03:03 b.sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  7 03:03 a.sh
```

The command/script used will perform the following steps:

1. It will find all the files in the directory.
2. remove the ./ from their front (as result of find command).
3. grep out any filename containing a dot, which means an extension (eg: c.sh has a dot, so it will be filtered).
4. read the filename list, one by one, prepare its new name using (new=`echo $file|sed "s/$old_session//g"`) command.
5. rename is using mv command.
6. print out the operation result.
7. display the ls -lrth output after processing for verification.

## Here is the command/script and its output.

```
bash$> find . -type f | sed 's/^\.\///g' | grep -v "\." | while read file
> do
> new=`echo $file|sed "s/$old_session//g"`
> mv $file ${new}_${new_session}
> echo "$file renamed to ${new}_${new_session}"
> done
ls -lrt
123kkk renamed to 123_noname
222kkk renamed to 222_noname
334kkk renamed to 334_noname
3432kkk renamed to 3432_noname
190kkk renamed to 190_noname
bash$> ls -lrt
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  7 03:03 c.sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  7 03:03 b.sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  7 03:03 a.sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  7 03:09 3432_noname
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  7 03:09 334_noname
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  7 03:09 222_noname
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  7 03:09 123_noname
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct  7 03:09 190_noname
bash$>
```

Comment: This code is really quite buggy. At least fix the quoting issues identified by http://shellcheck.net/, and switch from `echo $file` to `printf '%s\n' "$file"` -- see [the POSIX specification for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html) to appreciate how wide the range of circumstances is in which its output is undefined.

Comment: it would be both more efficient and more correct to instead write `new=${file//$old_session/}`, thus not needing either `echo` or `sed` at all. At that point you'd still just have your quoting bugs.

Comment: ...well, not *just* the quoting bugs. Not using the `-r` argument to `read` means backslashes in filenames would be silently deleted. And not clearing `IFS` on the `read` means you'd be silently deleting trailing whitespace in the filenames. And not using NUL-delimited strings means filenames containing literal newlines would be trouble.

Comment: Wow.. I didn't know all of that. Thank you for pointing that , I will try them and update my answer. I had not thought of all those things, when I was writing it, but you have made me realize that now.

Comment: re: the NUL-delimited string approach, see [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) for some examples -- search for `-print0`; you can also search for that same argument in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).